# What does second argument here "typedef void fv(int), (*pfv)(int)"

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

Here is code which disturbing me:

`typedef void fv(int), (*pfv)(int)`

It seems it does definition of function fv which takes int as first argument, but what does mean here second part `(*pfv)(int)`?

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=typedef%20void%20fv%28int%29%2C%20%28%2Apfv%29%28int%29

Comment: Don't write code like that. Use `typedef void fv(int);` ... `fv* ptr;`. Hiding pointers behind typedefs are bad practice and in this case it goes for function pointers too.

Answer (score 2):

It has two typedefs; one defines a typedef called `fv` that points to a function type and the other a pointer-to-function type `pfv`.

```
typedef void fv(int), (*pfv)(int)
```

Indeed, one could have instead written

```
typedef void fv(int);
typedef fv *pfv;
```

i.e. define `fv` as a *typedef* for the function *type*, and define `pfv` as a pointer to the said function type.

Note that in nowhere are we defining or declaring a function; however you can use the `fv` typedef *then* to *declare* a function:

```
fv foo;
```

is the same as declaring

```
void foo(int);
```

---

And finally, it is more opinionated, but generally using typedefs to hide pointers is not preferred, so instead of using `pfv` to define a pointer to the function type, you could just use `fv *` to declare these pointers everywhere:

```
fv *funcp = foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a function taking an integer argument and returning void.
A hint comes from the variable name. **p**ointer to a **f**unction returning **v**oid.

Expanding

```
typedef void fv(int);
typedef void (*pfv)(int);
```

The brackets here are necessary (*pfv) to distinguish from the case

```
void *fpv(int);
```

a function returning a pointer to a void.

You may find [this article](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/31818/typedef-for-function-pointers) helpful.

Comment: So in my code it's just multiple definition?

Comment: Yes, two declarations on a single line.